# Custom universal listener/hook in android

Tags: android, listener

I want to write a class that I will use as some driver/connector with same API.
But not in every request I will received the same data.

So the best solution is to create in this class event

```
onVariableOneNameChangeListener(String variableOne)
```

and attach it to any element in layout element (EditText, TextView, etc).

So how to build the class with universal attaching event?

Answer (score 0):

Not certain what you mean. Do you want a listener that can respond to any event on any View?This probably isn't possible, because each event listener has its own signature. Can you elaborate on the use case?